# Extract colour format pdf into excel in same color

Tags: java

can anyone please let me know how to extract colour format text from pdf into excel in same colour format using java ? PFA snap

I am using java 17 but not able to extract same colour text pdf into excel the output in excel coming in black colour only not in coloured format text.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u67I6.png)

I need java code of above problem